# Line Login Failure

Tags: php, oauth, line

While integrating line login, I received "Authentication Failed" continuously even though I have given correct email and password.

This is the  url I [tried](https://access.line.me/dialog/oauth/weblogin?response_type=code&client_id=xxxx&redirect_uri=http://example.com/line/line.php&state=check).

Please help how to overcome this

Comment: yes..but i did given correct mail id and password..

Comment: Its Working now!!!!

To make it working, you have to register your mail id that you are going to log in in line channel registration

Answer (score 0):

Its Working now!!!! To make it working, you have to register your mail id  as a developer of channel while line channel registration